# Call ajax in file .js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have a problem with this :

```
function inicioConsultar(){
$(function(){
    $('#serviciosU').change(function(){
        if ($('#serviciosU').val()!= "-1")
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("ObtenerCapas")",
                data: {urlServicioUsuario:$("#serviciosU :selected").val()},
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                error: function() {
                    alert("An error occurred.");
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var items = "";
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        items += "<option value=\"" + item.Value + "\">" + item.Text +     "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#capas").html(items);
                }
            });
        }
    })
});
```

I put in my Index.cshtml "inicioConsultar()" and there is a problem with ajax, because if i delete the call ajax everything it is ok.

In loyout, i load jquery and the index it is inside layout.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: What is the problem?  What is the error?

Comment: Can you show your HTML as well?

Comment: the error is that not recognise the function "inicioConsultar()", but if i delete the ajax call, everything it is ok!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a syntax error:

```
"@Url.Action("ObtenerCapas")",
```

That isn't how strings work in JavaScript. You need to escape the inner double quotes, as they're terminating the string.

Try

```
"@Url.Action(\"ObtenerCapas\")",
```

However, that wont' solve your problem, unless `@Url.Action(...)` is a real URL on your server, or your AJAX set has some kind of ability to evaluate that string as a function call.

Comment: Or, consequently "@Url.Action('ObtenerCapas')"

Comment: but before this code was in my index and it doesnt have problem!

Comment: That's unlikely. That has never been valid JavaScript. Is your Index file preprocessed in some way?

Comment: i tried this but it doesnt work, the error it is the same
"Error: ReferenceError: 'inicioConsultar' is undifened, function Consultar"

Comment: well, i tried onther time because in the same file i have more ajax call and this is the problem!!!
Thanks very much, and sorry for my english